# Unicode display in Microsoft Expression Web 4

Tags: html, unicode, expression-web, microsoft-expression-web

I have a HTML document with Greek and Hebrew letters in it. When I open the HTML file in Notepad, or Internet Explorer, or Firefox, the Greek and Hebrew letters display perfectly. See below:

[image: Good]

However, if I open the very same HTML document in Microsoft's Expression Web 4, the Greek and Hebrew characters are lost. See below:

[image: Bad example]

Why does Expression Web 4 fail to do what Notepad, Firefox and IE can do, that is, display the correct characters?

You can find the original source HTML document here:

http://hostsafe.com/temp/Adami-nekeb.html

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, Expression Web 4 does not interpret the document properly as UTF-8 encoding, even though the page you mention has its encoding declared with the `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` tag. Instead, Expression Web 4 interprets it as windows-1252 encoded. You can see this if you open the page on a browser and manually force the browser to use windows-1252 (View → Encoding, select “Western” or “West Europea” or “windows-1252” or whatever looks similar to those). The texts then get garbled exactly as in your examples.

There is probably some command in Expression Web 4 to make it use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

It works properly in my Expression Web 4, but you need to use a full header:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```